# Way to fetch data periodically in Scala without var/mutable collection

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scalaz

I want to fetch data from some source periodically, once per hour. I do it this way, because data fetching costs a lot of time, about 10 minutes. So, I cache this data.

I have such code right now:

```
import java.util._

object Loader {
    @volatile private var map: Map[SomeKey, SomeValue] = Map()

    def start() {
        val timer = new Timer()
        val timerTask = new TimerTask {
            override def run() {
                reload()
            }
        }
        val oneHour = 60 * 60 * 1000
        timer.schedule(timerTask, oneHour)
    }

    def reload() {
        map = loadMap()
    }

    // this method invocation costs a lot, so, I cache it in reload()
    def loadMap(): Map[SomeKey, SomeValue] = ...

    def getValue(key: SomeKey): Option[SomeValue] = map.get(key)
}
```

Also, I have `Loader.start()` invocation in my `main()` function.

This works good, but I'd like to know, is there some way to write it in more functional way: get rid of var without just using mutable collection?

Comment: If you use a (volatile) `var`, the `Map` does not have to be mutable (which btw seems to be the case in the code above)

Comment: @BrunoGrieder yes, Map doesn't have to be mutable, and it isn't. The question is, can we get rid of this var somehow without just using mutable map. I edited my question to be more clear.

Comment: If you want to change state and maintain it, something will have to be mutable. Maybe you can get away by encapsulating State in a Monad Transformer and "carrying" the state through but I cannot even start to imagine how this would look like. ScalaZ experts may jump in here

Comment: The state of the object (a cache) mutates periodically. There is nothing wrong with using mutable structures (either `var` or `mutable` collections) to represent that. Even the Scala libraries use mutable elements in their implementations. The thing to be avoided is shared mutable state, but local, non-shared mutable state is fine. I know this is not an answer, but the question seems more practical than academic, so I feel it's appropriate to point out that there is no reason to avoid mutables in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A compositional IO library, [scalaz-stream](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz-stream), succeeds in keeping mutability away from your code in such use cases. First, the dependencies:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scalaz" %% "scalaz-core" % "7.2.8",
  "org.scalaz" %% "scalaz-concurrent" % "7.2.8",
  "org.scalaz.stream" %% "scalaz-stream" % "0.8.6a"
)
```

We start with some imports from `scalaz-concurrent` and `scalaz-stream`:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scalaz.concurrent.Task
import scalaz.stream.time._
import scalaz.stream._
import scalaz.stream.Process.Env
import scalaz.stream.ReceiveY._
```

Suppose we have an imperative data source capable of extracting its snapshot. For demonstration, it also updates itself on every extraction:

```
trait DataSource[Key, Value] {

  def loadMap: Map[Key, Value]
}

object DataSourceStub extends DataSource[Int, String] {

  private var externalSource: Map[Int, String]  = Map(1 -> "a")

  def loadMap: Map[Int, String] = {
    val snapshot = externalSource
    val key = snapshot.keys.max
    val value = snapshot(key)
    val (newKey, newValue) = (key + 1) -> (value + "a")
    val newSource = snapshot + (newKey -> newValue)
    externalSource = newSource
    snapshot
  }
}
```

Now, we start `Loader` implementation by introducing `timer` that emits a unit event immediately on starting it and then emits every `refreshEvery` seconds. Then, event stream reporting our `cacheStates` can be obtained by mapping data-receiving `Task` to every event and evaluating them within stream. The hard part is commutation: we need to interleave a stream of `Request`s (functions that perform some action using data from cache) with our periodical stream of snapshots. `scalaz-stream` offers a stream commutation tool, `Wye`, which allows us to state in which order we'll process events from input streams. We need an initial cache snapshot to work with, so we start from `wye.receiveL`, moving to `handleImpl` with initial cache state. Now, we can receive any event with `receiveBoth`:

- if it's a cache snapshot update, we recur on it without producing output;
- if it's a request, we give it current cache state and emit resulting `Task` into output, also recurring on current state;
- if one of input streams terminates, we stop processing.

The only remaining thing is to join our inputs with `handle` `Wye` and include side effects of processing tasks into stream, which we do in `processRequests`.

```
class Loader[Key, Value](dataSource: DataSource[Key, Value], refreshEvery: Duration) {

  type CacheState = Map[Key, Value]
  type Request = CacheState => Task[Unit]
  type ReaderEnv = Env[CacheState, Request]

  implicit val scheduler: ScheduledExecutorService = DefaultScheduler

  private val timer: Process[Task, Unit] =
    Process.emit(()) ++ awakeEvery(refreshEvery).map(_ => ())

  private val cacheStates: Process[Task, CacheState] =
    timer.evalMap(_ => Task(dataSource.loadMap))

  private val handle: Wye[CacheState, Request, Task[Unit]] = {
    def handleImpl(current: CacheState): Wye[CacheState, Request, Task[Unit]] = {
      import wye._
      import Process._
      receiveBoth {
        case ReceiveL(i) => handleImpl(i)
        case ReceiveR(i) => emit(i(current)) ++ handleImpl(current)
        case HaltOne(rsn) => Halt(rsn)
      }
    }
    wye.receiveL[CacheState, Request, Task[Unit]](handleImpl)
  }

  def processRequests(requests: Process[Task, Request]): Process[Task, Unit] =
    cacheStates.wye(requests)(handle).eval
}
```

Let's test our data loader by issuing 100 requests of data by max id (100 ms each) to it while performing refresh every second:

```
object TestStreamBatching {

  private val loader = new Loader(DataSourceStub, 1.second)

  private def request(cache: loader.CacheState): Task[Unit] = Task {
    Thread.sleep(100)
    val key = cache.keys.max
    val value = cache(key)
    println(value)
  }

  private val requests: Process[Task, loader.Request] =
    Process.unfold(100)(s => if(s > 0) Some((request, s - 1)) else None)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    loader.processRequests(requests).run.unsafePerformSync
  }
}
```

By running it, you can see a ladder of `'a'` letters that increases its riser size every second, eventually terminating after 100 outputs.

Comment: By the way, we can use akka-streams too in this case :)

Comment: Note, however, that akka-streams, while being a good implementation of backpressure streams, is an imperative design that's not bothering to preserve referential transparency or even have such notion. When implementing functional programming constructs with it, you need to carefully watch that it won't do anything in background on seemingly non-effectful call (like Scala's `Future` constructor that immediately launches supplied function).